# How to send back the model data from jsp to controller

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a controller which sets few values to a model and sends to jsp. In jsp i need to show those values(as labels) along with additional values from user as input values. When i submit the jsp i only get valid values that user has entered and the values set earlier by controller is null.

### JSP

```
<form:form
                action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/deviceAction.html"
                modelAttribute="deviceData">
                <table class="gridtable" width="500px">

                    <tr>
                        <td>Device Name : </td>
                        <td>${deviceData.deviceName}</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Model Name : </td>
                        <td>${deviceData.modelName}</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Serial No : </td>
                        <td>${deviceData.serialNo}</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Device Id : </td>
                        <td>${deviceData.deviceId}</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Status : </td>
                        <td>${deviceData.statusCode}</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Action : <span class="required">*</span></td>
                        <td>
                            <form:select path="deviceAction" >
                                <form:option value="" label="--- Select ---" />
                                <form:options items="${model.actionList}" />
                            </form:select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btn_submit">
            </form:form>
```

Controller:

```
    public ModelAndView beforeSubmit() {
        ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView();

    DeviceData deviceData = new DeviceData();
        deviceData.setDevicePk("123");
        deviceData.setAccessToken("abcwetrwertewrtetr");
        deviceData.setDeviceId("deferterterterterwtetetertg");
        deviceData.setDeviceName("test");
        deviceData.setEnrolledDate("7-8-13");
        deviceData.setModelName("test1");
        deviceData.setSerialNo("test2dsfgdfgdfg");
        deviceData.setStatusCode("test3");
        List<String> actionList = getActionList();
        Map<String, List<String>> model = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        model.put("actionList", actionList);
        modelView.addObject("deviceData", deviceData);
        modelView.addObject("model", model);
        modelView.setViewName("admin/tokenSearchResult");

}

public ModelAndView afterSubmit() {
@ModelAttribute("deviceData") DeviceData deviceData, BindingResult result) {
        logger.info("#################device datas are : " + deviceData.getDevicePk() + "###### " + deviceData.getDeviceAction());
        return new ModelAndView();
}
```

deviceData.getDevicePk() is null

Only the drop down value is having valid value. Other values displayed in the screen are received as null.

Edit:

Till now i have found only one solution:

```
<form:input path="deviceName" readonly="true" />
```

But this way UI does not looks good. The editable and non editable values mixup in the screen. Looking for a better answer

Finally i am using hidden parameters to solve the problem.

Example:

```
<td>${deviceData.deviceName}</td>
```

is replaced by:

```
<td><form:hidden path="deviceName"</td>
```

By this way it helps me to avoid any css work(which i am not much comfortable)

If anyone get a better solution kindly post it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make them into form inputs using the [Spring form tags](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/spring-form.tld.html) in much the same way as you have for the form:select. If they are not editable by the user, you can always disable them.

Comment: Tried the suggestion given by Mark, in this way the UI looks lik a non editable text field. But i want the UI to look like as a label text.

Comment: You can use the power of CSS to style it to look however you want.  If the controller values are now being resubmitted with the form then I think your original question is answered. If you want CSS help, you will get more attention if you ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can simple hide those input. For example :

```
<input type="hidden" name="VehSeriesModelId" value="${vehDetailsVM.id }">
```

This way, you can get the data to the `controller` and the user will also not be able to edit the value. On the other hand, your `form` will also not show it :)